# Como consigo impedir que sistemas incorporem meu site?

Tags: php, email

A pouco tempo descobri que pessoas estão acessando meu site com um aplicativo de divulgação (Site Marketing).

Ai toda vez vem de diferentes "pessoas", com dados diferentes porém com as mesmas características.

Começa com um texto e no fim alguns links.

Descobri também que a ferramenta impede que JavaScrips rodem junto com a página e simulam versão do Internet Explorer 6.

1. Qual seria a ideia, bloquear o acesso via iframe. Impedir que a
   página rode em versões desatualizadas de tais navegadores.
2. Impedir que a página rode em versões desatualizadas de tais navegadores.
3. Colocando campo "CPF" com verificação (Validação) que no caso já está inativo.

Comment: Já tentou usar captcha.

Comment: Nada disso vai resolver. Mais fácil é impedir textos com links e determinadas palavras chave, ou criar um passo extra nestes casos (caso haja link, mostra um captcha, assim só 'incomoda' usuários suspeitos). - Uma coisa que eu costumo fazer é criar campos falsos no formulário, e esconder com css. Se algum for preenchido, é sinal de bot. Além disso, só o fato de verificar no servidor se alguns campos não respeitam máscaras, e devolver o formulário para o usuário corrigir, já impede muito bot. Nos meus sistemas eu já tenho uma lista negra de palavras chave, que serve como proteção extra.

Comment: Mais uma proteção: se mandar num campo hidden um timestamp com chave de segurança, e receber resposta em tempo curto demais é pq o formulário foi preenchido por um bot. Neste caso, captcha neles para efetivar o envio.

Comment: Então ainda ontem eu descobri que essa m... de programa da enviar sozinho no formulário.

Fiz o bloqueio do iframe e já parei de receber spams, eu recebo mensagem solicitando o serviço da minha empresa algo em torno de 50 por dia,  20 seriam de "clientes" e os outros 30 seriam de spamers, que no caso enchem o saco e muito. 

Caso continuem irei fazer essa opção dos campos ocultos com css já que se por "hidden" a merda do bot não preenche e se por oculto com css certamente ele preencherá com alguma coisa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gente só reabrindo a pergunta que eu mesmo fiz, dei uma fuçada mais além, juntei algumas idéias aqui do post, e fiz o seguinte.

No próprio formulário eu botei um campo oculto com nome muito similar que possui na ferramenta, o campo era do tipo **text** e não **hidden** e foi oculto com css.

Com isso eu resolvi em 100% os **spans** que era recebidos em todos os e-mails que eram disparado a partir do form. Nenhum e-mail com links, ou com conteúdo semelhante foi recebido!

**CASO RESOLVIDO.**

Comment: Isso parece [POG](https://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Gambiarras)

Comment: @samuelrvg é um POG dos que mais funciona, e não atrapalha usuários convencionais (como um captcha faria). O único cuidado é fazer as devidas entradas e acertar campos _aria_ para não confundir deficientes visuais.  Consegue propor algo melhor? Seria legal alguma resposta alternativa para a comunidade votar.

Answer (score 4):

> "Descobri também que a ferramenta impede que JavaScrips rodem junto com a página e simulam versão do Internet Explorer 6."

Existem inclusive softwares que não são navegadores que enviam/recebem dados via HTTP(S), como por exemplo o CURL. Não muito distante existe o LYNX Browser, que é simplesmente em texto, *um navegador em CMD*. Além disso até mesmo o Chrome e navegadores "reais" são capazes de desligar o javascript, nas suas configurações.

---

**Qual seria a ideia, bloquear o acesso via iframe.**

Existe, o *header*/cabeçalho de `X-Frame-Options` ([RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034)), desde 2013, ele tem como objetivo impedir que um website abra em um `<iframe>` ou em um `<frame>`, logo utilize:

*NGINX:*

```
  add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
```

Mas se o navegador for obsoleto? Se o navegador não interpreta o `X-Frame-Options` isto será ignorado.

**Impedir que a página rode em versões desatualizadas de tais navegadores.**

Isso é inútil, uma pessoa mal intencionada consegue rapidamente falsificar um User-Agent, o próprio CURL, que não é navegador consegue se passar por um navegador rápido e fácil.

Qualquer Burp Suite permite alterar os headers, qualquer CURL permite definir os headers, isto:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" https://seu-site.com
```

Faz o seu website entender que está acessando via Chrome na versão 41, inclusive o CURL tem uma função `-A` especialmente para alterar o `User-Agent`, sem ter que usar o `-H`, *legal não*?!

Uma coisa que pode fazer para *quebrar* navegadores antigos e impedir que navegadores antigos sejam utilizados é utilizar TLS 1.2. Somente para deixar claro o TLS 1.2 **não foi feito para isto** porém somente [navegadores recentes e sistemas operacionais recentes possuem suporte a ele](http://caniuse.com/#search=tls%201.2), ou seja é uma eliminação "natural".

**Colocando campo "CPF" com verificação (Validação) que no caso já está inativo.**

É mais rápido gerar um CPF do que gerar um MD5, por exemplo isto gera um CPF válido:

```
$CPF = '';
$D10 = $D11 = 0;

// Gera 9 números individuais pseudo-aleatorios criptograficamente seguros
for($i = 0; $i < 9; ++$i)
    $CPF .= random_int(0, 9);

// Calculo do 10º número
for($i = 0; $i < 9; ++$i)
    $D10 += $CPF[$i] * (10 - $i);

// Acrescenta o 10º número ao CPF (Se for maior que dez é 0, se não é ele mesmo!)
$CPF .= 11 - ($D10 % 11) >= 10 ? 0 : 11 - ($D10 % 11);

// Calculo do 11º número
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
    $D11 += $CPF[$i] * (11 - $i);

// Acrescenta o 11º número ao CPF (Se for maior que dez é 0, se não é ele mesmo!)
$CPF .= 11 - ($D11 % 11) >= 10 ? 0 : 11 - ($D11 % 11);

echo $CPF;
```

Você consegue gerar milhares de CPF *sem custo nenhum*, uma pessoa mal-intencionada continuará utilizando e fazendo várias e várias requisições normalmente. A única maneira seria se você verificasse se o CPF condiz com o nome e outros dados, mesmo assim muitos dados podem ser obtido procurando no próprio Google.

> Observação essa função foi criada [baseada nesta publicação](https://gurudoexcel.com/como-e-feito-o-calculo-de-validacao-cpf/).

---

Você criar restrição por CPF e exigir vários dados vai afastar usuários legítimos. Assim como bloquear navegadores antigos, somente tende a reduzir o número de visitas legitimas, sem nenhum grande beneficio. Lógico se utilizar o TLS 1.2, *e como consequência impedir navegadores antigos*, o seu site estará mais seguro do que SSLv2 e SSLv3, *porém bloquear por bloquear não trará nenhum beneficio*.

Além disso quem realmente querer manipular irá conseguir usando CURL ou seja lá o que for, falsificando um User-Agent, que na verdade se usarem eles já falsificam (e você nem tem como descobrir).

---

**Soluções eficientes:**

1. Utilizar o `X-Frame-Options` para navegadores modernos não permitirem iframe, *se limitar por TLS 1.2 obrigatoriamente ele suportará este cabeçalho*.
2. Adicionar captcha poderia aumentar o custo para falsificações, *pode criar um pequeno inconveniente para o usuário*.
3. Definir um `Content-Security-Policy` para também impedir o `<iframe>` e também XSS.
4. Criar um `Rate-Limit` caso um único IP envie muitas requisições e bloquei-o prevenindo novos envios, *se este for o caso*.
5. Criar formulários falsos, *não visíveis para humanos*, como sugerido por @Bacco, pode ser eficiente.

Comment: Pow cara gostei bastante da sua ideia, que como disse acima já fiz e pelo que verifiquei os e-mails pararam de vim os SPAM.
Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seu problema é totalmente relacionado a algum ataque de BOTs, ou seja seu problema não é de incluírem seu site em outro lugar, mas sim um ou mais BOTs que tentam quebrar a segurança do seu site, ou até mesmo tentam causar algum tipo de ataque em massa para derrubar.

Então a questão aqui não é um problema de XSS (Cross-site scripting), mas sim um ataque direto.

A sua [solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277952/3635) de criar um campo oculto, realmente eu não entendi, mas se for o que imagino, qualquer BOT pode facilmente detectar isto e passar por cima em breve.

As soluções existentes para resolver este tipo de problema hoje são:

- Criar um captcha de imagem próprio
- Usar [*recaptcha*](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html)
- Usar serviços como o https://www.cloudflare.com/ - mais detalhes em https://www.cloudflare.com/br/waf/